# How to detect when nginx reload is done transferring traffic?

Tags: nginx

I'm managing my own blue/green deploys by:

1. starting a new version of the app
2. updating the nginx configuration to point to the new app
3. sending the reload signal to nginx
4. stopping and cleaning up the old app

It works pretty well but I still have few seconds of downtime because I kill the old server before traffic has fully migrated to the new app. Is there a way to know when nginx is done retiring the worker processes that send traffic to the old app?

Comment: Maybe I could count the number of worker processes and wait until they return to normal.

Comment: Rather monitor your app and stop it when it is no longer processing any traffic.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That'd be nice but I'm not sure how to do that in an automated fashion.

Answer (score 2):

Realizing that:

1. nginx has a set number of worker processes
2. reload works by spinning up an equal number of new processes for the new config and then retiring the old ones when traffic is no longer going to them

I decided to just count the number of worker processes and wait until it returns to normal. Like this:

```sh
function nginx-workers {
  echo $(ps -ef | grep "nginx: worker process" | grep -v grep | wc -l)
}

# Get the original number of worker processes.
# I made it generic so that it works on machines of any size.
numWorkerProcesses=$(nginx-workers)

# Issue the reload signal.
sudo nginx -s reload

# Wait for the number of workers to return to normal.
while [ $(nginx-workers) -ne $numWorkerProcesses ]
do
  sleep 1;
done;

# Reload is complete and I can safely retire the old service.
```

Comment: There's still a bit of a hiccup when nginx is reloading but it's reduced.